# Why does gitlab icon change shade

Tags: gitlab

I have noticed that gitlab has a different shade of icon and I can't figure out what makes the icon change.

The one on the left is the more common logo.

The one on the right is the shade I noticed start to appear several months ago.

[image: gitlab icon samples]

What does the lighter shade icon represent?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it has something to do with their new interface.

It's odd -- contrary to what @sytech posted, I've noticed that I sometimes have multiple tabs open *to the same GitLab page* (e.g. an open MR) and one of them has the orange icon and the other has the yellow one. For example, right now:
[image]

Flipping between the two tabs, I see that the one with the yellow icon has the word "next" inserted next to the gitlab logo up at the top-left, whereas the other one doesn't:
[image]

Clicking on it lands me on a page where I can flip a toggle to use their new interface. Clicking the toggle instantly changes the favicon:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

GitLab.com has, for at least a couple years now, used the yellow tanuki favicon to make it easier to distinguish from the default favicon used in self-managed instances.

You'll also see different favicons used in different portions of the site to help identify tabs quickly.

A couple historical issues will evidence this:

[Yellow tanuki being shown outside canary releases (2018)](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/24499)

[a 2020 issue related favicons, but with a screenshot showing the yellow tanuki favicon](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/www-gitlab-com/-/issues/7823)

Comment: These icons are on the same instance of gitlab hosted gitlab.

Comment: @BeKindToNewUsers gitlab.com will use the standard orange on their promotional/informational pages like about.gitlab.com -- but will use the yellow tanuki on issues/repositories, etc. Like I mentioned, different favicons help identify different parts of the site. Does that help?